# If others permission is writable of a directory, other users can modify a file even the file is not writable

Tags: bash, ubuntu, debugging, vim, permissions

> user1@server1:/locdisk/data/a$ **touch test**
>
> user1@server1:/locdisk/data/a$ **ll**
>
> rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1 1 AUG 30 11:11 ./
>
> rwx------ 1 **user1 user1** 1 AUG 30 11:11 test
>
> user2@server2:~$ **ssh server1**
>
> user2@server1:~$ **vi /locdisk/data/a/test**

and then modify test by 'w!'

> user2@server1:~$ **ll /locdisk/data/a/**
>
> rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1 1 AUG 30 11:11 ./
>
> rwx------ 1 **user2 user2** 3 AUG 30 11:11 test

How could it be??

My ubuntu has a bug? How should I fix it?

Comment: See [Vim writes to file without having permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266037/vim-writes-to-file-without-having-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu does not have a bug. This is how Unix file systems work. There are a number of issues here.

First, you should read the link provided by Mark Plotnick in his comment. You will see that you are not writing to the file, but merely changing the directory. And because you have write-permissions on the directory, that is allowed.

Second: this is why, in Unix/Linux, you should never ever have world writable directories.

Third, are you sure your `vi /locdisk/data/a/test` does not complain about the file not being readable? So you cannot modify the file, you can overwrite it however.